# Ruby Exception.to_s doesn't match expected string

Tags: ruby

I have a rescue block which checks for the correct exception thrown or not as follows:

```
rescue Exception
      if $!.to_s() != "myException"
        Err("Unexpected error :" + $!)
      end
      else
        Err("No error")
```

My `$!.to_s()` contains large strings as follows when I `puts` like:

```
puts $!.to_s()
```

Output of above `puts` before `if` statement is:

```
myException \n
th sdfsj dsjhf sdfj \n
asdj jkds fdf j
```

So in `if` statement I want to compare the first line from output of `$!.to_s()` with string in double quotes.

Any suggestions how to resolve this?

Comment: "Correct exception being thrown"? You aren't coding by exception, are you?

Comment: Thanks Femaref, but in my scenario i need to check the exception message with expected string of exception in case of Exception thrown.

Answer (score 9):

That makes my eyes hurt. Please do object-oriented programming in ruby.

```
class MyException < StandardError; end
```

will define a new exception you can rescue by

```
begin
  do_something_that_raises_expected_exception
rescue MyException
  do_something_else
end
```

So you won't need any String comparison.

If you want to go down your road, use `string.match exception_name`, but I advise against it.

Another word on rescuing: Don't do `rescue Exception` if possible, just use `rescue`, because `Exception` captures stuff like `SyntaxError` too (which is likely not intended). And exceptions are frowned upon for flow control in `ruby`, as opposed to `python`.

Comment: Thanks Tass, but i dont want to change other stuff, only thing is to compare first line from output of $!.to_s() with string that i have provided in "" quotes.

Comment: That's the part with `exception_name`. But please file a bug on that.

Answer (score 3):

Although I fully agree with [Tass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179802/how-to-compare-string-in-if-statment-in-ruby/8179880#8179880), here is how you can achieve what you want:

```
if $!.to_s !~ /\AmyException\s*\n/
  ...
```

or

```
if $!.to_s.lines.first != "myException \n"
  ...
```

But please: Don't do that.

Comment: Is it just me or does that look like "AmyExceptions" :P